# if $(ab)^{3}=e\Rightarrow(ba)^{3}=e$, this is true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

for $a,b\in G$ (G is a group)

I have to prove that $if (ab)^{3}=e\Rightarrow(ba)^{3}=e$ or to give an example that this is false...

I belive it false and I try to find an exaple - please help and tell if I'm right (and I'd like to get an exaple) or I wrong...

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$a(babab)=e$$ so $$babab=a^{-1}$$ and so $$(babab)a=a^{-1}a=e$$

Comment: Great! Thank you! I didn't tought that is so simple!!
(I try something like this...But I didn't succeed).

Comment: @YoavFridman If this answered your question, please mark it as solved. You can do this by clicking on the grey checkmark next to the answer; it will turn green then.